# How to solve linear system of equations in 1 and inf-norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, linear-programming, normed-spaces

I have the problem to find a linear program that is equivalent to solving the problem that finds a minimum for $||Ax-b||_1$ and $||Ax-b||_{\infty}$.

We defined a linear program as follows:

$min_{x} c^Tx $ where c is some vector

$\mathcal{A}x = \mathcal{b}$

$x \ge 0$

But I have difficulties to transform the two problems in this form.

Comment: You might find help here: reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/AdvancedDocumentation/LinearAlgebra/7.3.html

Comment: somehow this link does not work

Comment: Strange, now? http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/AdvancedDocumentation/LinearAlgebra/7.3.html

Comment: no, thank you very much